# Detect apple touch icon even though htaccess/htpasswd is used

Tags: ios, apache, .htaccess

I currently have a setup where I have a htaccess document on an Apache server limiting the access of a website as such:

```
AuthUserFile /myapps/.htpasswd
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

This prompts the website visitor for a username and password (as specified in a .htpasswd file).

This works fine for my purposes (displaying prototypes in HTML).

When testing the prototypes on smartphones or tablets I would like the apple touch icon to show up. However, because of the .htaccess the request to `apple-touch-icon.png` fails.

Is there a way to work around this without changing the htaccess/htpasswd setup?

I can move the apple touch icon to a different location, but I am unable (unskilled enough? :)) to change my security/auth setup to something else. It's a prototype after all and no real application.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to find it but here's the solution to my answer. FilesMatch takes a regex that allows you to exclude some files from the authentication.

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

# Allow access to apple touch icon without authing
<FilesMatch "(apple-touch-icon\.png)">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```